# how to declare a subset from a set in cplex?

Tags: set, subset, cplex, opl

i am a new in Cplex , so i want to know how to declare a subset included in a set .
i have a    S_i : the set of flight i's Feasible start time tuples.
and i declare this et like this :

```
        int F=...;
        range flights = 1..F; // set of flights
        {int} S[flights]=...; //Set of feasible start time
```

and i have a subset S_i (w) ⊆ S_i denote the subset of feasible start time tuples , if w working stations assigned are assigned to flight i.

i declare :

```
int W=...;
range workingstations=1..W;
```

but i couldn' t know how to declare the subset, Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
{string} flights={"A1","A2"};
{string} workingstations={"W1","W2"};

tuple tup {


int sd ; //start time of bagage handling
  int sh ; // start time of storage depletion

}
{tup} ttt = {};
tuple Starttime {
  int elt; //earlist_starttime
  int lst; //lastest_starttime
  int  ed; //end time of baggage handling
  tup tt;
  
  }
  
  tup myt1=<3,4>;
  tup myt2=<4,5>;
  
  
  
Starttime S[flights]=[<1,2,3,myt1>,<1,2,9,myt2>];
Starttime S2[flights][workingstations]=[[<1,2,3,myt1>,<1,2,9,myt2>],[<1,2,3,myt1>,<1,2,9,myt2>]];

execute PREPROCESSING {
//initialize tup
  var t1 = ttt.add(1,11);
  var t2 = ttt.add(2,22);
  
  writeln(ttt);
  writeln(S);
  writeln(S2);
  }
//variables
dvar int+ sd ;
dvar int+ sh;

subject to
{
  
}
```

works

Comment: hello DEar Sir Alex , thanks for your response , i want to know how to use the second set S2 with the decision variable !!! that mean the index of that Set , i have a decision variable x (i)(c) (w)(t2) in which i , c , w , t2 the index of flights , carousels, workingstations , and the set S2 that you declared Sir ,so i declare the decision variable x like that :  'dvar boolean x[flights][carousels][workingstations][t2 in S2[i][w]]; but it show me an error "The Start Time [flights] [workingstations] type cannot be used with "in".

Comment: and the  another  error "Variable indexer size not allowed for a generic array." Second question Sir :how to declare it on the sum ??? i writed like this : sum( t2 in S2) x[i][c][w][t2]== 1; but also the same error

Comment: dvar boolean x[flights][carousels][workingstations][t2 in S2[i][w]]; is not allowed since all dimensions should have a given size and not depend on another previous size.

Comment: Could you explain more Dear Sir !! i didn't understand !!! So the using of the Set S2 in x how can be ??